# Sidebar fields in the 'IN Searchroup' in SOSL?

Tags: sosl

I have read in the developer guide that I can also search for Sidebar fields but I was wondering what exactly does he mean by Sidebar fields ? I would be greatful if someone gave me some examples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please link to and quote the section of the documentation to which you are referring?

Comment: Here is the link, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_in.htm .

Comment: Please make an [edit] to incorporate what you're asking about into your question.

Answer (score 4):

`SIDEBAR FIELDS` means basically indexed fields. So, if you want to make any field searchable through SIDEBAR fields (its faster), just make it `ExternalId` in field definition.

**Understanding:**

1. In below image, ALL FIELDS returned `gene` in `Email` and `Title`

[image]

2. But in below image for SIDEBAR Fields, It returned only `Email` because Email is indexed.

[image]